# Hibernate sequence not generated

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, sequence

Im working on a Spring (not Boot!) project, with Hibernate and PostgreSQL database. I also use Flyway for migration.
I use Flyway to generate the schema of the database, and insert initial data to it with given SQL scripts in my resources folder. For this reason, I excluded the hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto property from my hibernate.properties file.
On the startup, the schema is created and the data is inserted to the database, but my problem is, that this way Hibernate doesn't generate its sequence, and I cant save data from the application:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "hibernate_sequence" does not exist
```

What can I do with this?

Comment: You should provide the schema. But the error message is saying `hibernate_sequence ` does not exist. So you have to create the sequence to DB and try.

Comment: I see. So its completely okay to create an SQL script manually, that creates the hibernate_sequence?

Comment: Yes it is. Cause hibernate can not produce schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a sequence like this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE hibernate_sequence START 1;
```

Comment: Now its better, but still have errors. The sequence is created, but now I cant insert data from the app, because
`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "user_pkey"
  Detail: Key (id)=(1) already exists.`
The order is the following: create hibernate_sequence, create tables, insert data. Seems like inserting the data not incrementing the value in hibernate_sequence?

Comment: Add `DEFAULT nextval(‘hibernate_sequence’)` to `id` in your schema

Answer (score 6):

As you didn't provide any code not sure what is wrong there, assume missing [@SequenceGenerator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/SequenceGenerator.html) annotation, I'll provide the one is working for me.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "your_table")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "your_table_id_seq", sequenceName = "your_table_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
public class YourTable implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "your_table_id_seq")
private Long id;
```

.
.
.

Comment: Thank you, I am looking forward to implement this solution too!