# getting error org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Sequence "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE" not found; SQL statement:

Tags: spring, spring-boot, h2

I am populating some data from data.sql file into H2 in memory database when my spring boot app starts. It has some values for Users entity with id 1,2,3 etc.

If I want to post new Users object i have to pass request body as

```json
{
  "id":1,
  "firstname": "fgjjd",
  "lastname": "gorfgjfgje",
  "age": 4,
  "gender": "M"
}
```

ideally i shouldn't pass "id" field because i have :

```java
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
```

why does it work only this way ?? If i pass some other id then i get

```
getting error org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Sequence "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE" not found; SQL statement:
```

Answer (score 0):

When you insert the data from the sql-file the application simply uses the existing id. But when you insert it using the application specific code, hibernates tries to request the new id using the given sequence. Unfortunately,  it seems like your sequence does not exists in the database.. Maybe this helps: [Hibernate sequence not generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44904380/hibernate-sequence-not-generated/44907459)

Answer (score 0):

While creating table use this, Auto-Increment - Sequence will be created internally & JPA will handle it with your code

```
person_id  int primary key generated always as identity (start with XX)
```

`Start with` is optional